# Unable to fit and center text in rectangle SVG javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

[This is the original graph](https://bl.ocks.org/cjrd/6863459) 
[And here's a fiddle for my version](https://fiddle.jshell.net/daw0qvav/2/)

I'm trying to replace the circles by rectangles so I can fit a long text into them to avoid wasting so much space. However, I'm unable to fit the text in the triangle and center it. I put the text-anchor attribute to middle but sometimes inherit is what works and sometimes not... Do you have any idea on how to fix this  ? Any additional advice on the layout will be much appreciated, I know my version sucks compared the the original, but i'm a beginner. 
Thanks !

drag/scroll to translate/zoom the graph
shift-click on graph to create a node
shift-click on a node and then drag to another node to connect them with a directed edge
shift-click on a node to change its title
click on node or edge and press backspace/delete to delete

Comment: Please update your fiddle with working images so we can see your problem in action.

Comment: the images dont matter they're for upload and download.

You hold down shift and click to make new rectangle. sorry I forgot to mention that

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the following  tag:

```
<center>the text that you want to place in center</center>
```

Comment: the tag is not visible somehow

Comment: the tag is <center></center>